# image tag showing syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I am having a problem in my query I am fetching data but the image tag is showing that there is a syntax problem .

```
> <?php
>     $query = "SELECT * from tbl_showrides";
>     $result = mysql_query($query);
>     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
>     $query_img = "SELECT image_name FROM tbl_rides_image WHERE
>     ride_id=".$row['id'].'  LIMIT 1';
>     $result_img = mysql_query($query_img);
>     $row_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_img);
>     <img src="<?php echo $base_url.'rides/'.$row_img['image_name']?>"/>
>     }
>     ?>
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: If there is a `"` in your php output , it could upset the resulting HTML.
Have you tried to view source and see in what way the image tag is not being set up correctly? Or is the error triggered by PHP itself?

Comment: What error checker is showing this syntax error? What, specifically,  does the error message say? Are you using an HTML syntax checker on PHP (if so, *that* is your problem, PHP is not HTML, use the right tool for the job).

Comment: Parse error: parse error in D:\wamp\www\autodealers\ride.php on line 315

Comment: What error checker is showing this syntax error?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you placed `<img>` tag (which is html code) without closing the php tag.
Simply change to :

```
 $row_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_img); ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $base_url.'rides/'.$row_img['image_name']?>"/>
 <?php }
```

I would also like to remind you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so it is advised that you switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for new projects.

Comment: Wow , I did not notice that. +1 for sharp eyes.

Comment: the previous one is solved now it is showing this error

Comment: the previous one is solved now it is showing this error

Comment: *Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resou*rce, boolean given in D:\wamp\www\autodealers\ride.php on line 314

Comment: If you're having a different problem, maybe you should try posting another question then. Follow the StackOverflow rules and guidelines.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\wamp\www\autodealers\ride.php on line 314

Answer (score 0):

You should not add `php` tag again inside the php tag..

```
<img src="<?php echo $base_url.'rides/'.$row_img['image_name']?>"/>
```

should be

```
$img = '<img src="'.$base_url.'rides/'.$row_img['image_name'].'"/>';
```